# Finding the difference in quantity of matching items from two sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two different sheets in Excel with two columns in each sheet. The first column contains the name of the item and the second column the quantity.

How do I get the difference in the quantities?

The items are unsorted in both the sheets, plus they are not in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is the `VLOOKUP()` function.

Set up `Sheet2` like this

[image: Worksheet 2 Screenshot]

and `Sheet1` like this

[image: Worksheet 1 Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `C2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill into the rest of the table's column:

```dart
=ABS(B2-VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$8,2,FALSE))
```

**Explanation:**

The `VLOOKUP()` function works by looking up the value of the first argument in the first column of the range specified in the second argument, and returns the value from the same row in the column specified by the third argument. (The third argument is a one-based column index of the columns of the range of the second argument.)

The `ABS()` function is just there to make all the differences positive. It can be omitted if you also need to know if the quantity in `Sheet2` in more or less than that in `Sheet1`.

The `#N/A` error results when the item in `Sheet1` doesn't have a corresponding entry in `Sheet2`. If required, this can be changed to any string by using the `IFERROR()` function.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Write this in Cell `G3` of `Sheet 2`  & fill it down.

   ```
     =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A3,$A$3:$B$9,2,False)-Sheet1!B3,"Not Found")
   ```
2. `VLOOKUP` function finds & match the Items between Sheets and Subtracts Quantity if found, otherwise `IFERROR` returns the `Not Found` message.

*Or you may use this one also in Cell `H3`of `Sheet 2` & fill it down.*

```
=IFERROR(ABS(IF(COUNTIF(A$3:A$9,Sheet1!A3)<>0,Sheet1!B3-INDEX(B$3:B$9,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,A$3:A$9,0))," ")),"Not Found")
```

1. In first part of the formula `COUNTIF` find the match between `Items` in both Sheets and if returns `1`, then the next part of the Formula `Subtracts Quantities` between Sheets which is supported by `INDEX & MATCH` combination.

**Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.**

Comment: Write your concern why this post has been Down voted ???